# In functional react, how to automatically simulate a button press immediately after a component renders?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

So let's suppose that there is some clickable widget in a component? How do I tell the window to automatically click that widget immediately after the component renders?

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
console.log('do something when loaded')
},[])`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `ref` using `hooks`

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const myBtnRef= useRef(null);

  useEffect(()=>{
    myBtnRef.click();
  }, []}

  return (
    <button ref={myBtnRef}>Click Me</button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the button is expected to be clicked after each rendering, the easiest way is

```
<button ref={() => console.log(`clicked`)}>Button</button>
```

You can add debounce in the callback to avoid redundant invocation.

If the button is expected to be clicked after each mounting, use the `useEffect` and `useRef` hooks.

```
const Containerr = () => {
  const btnRef = useRef(null)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.click()
  }, [])

  return (
    <button ref={btnRef}>Button</button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, in just one line but must be on the clickable element.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    document.getElementById('Id').click();
}, []}
```